# Trouble Aggregating terms that are pulled through an entity_reference

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, entities, css-js-aggregation

Trying to create a table view listing portfolio clients, including a list of tags that are related to each client. Tags are connected via entity_references (from multiple kinds of nodes), and it's breaking aggregation.

- I've got three content types: client, portfolio example, and explanation.
- Example and Explanation nodes each contain tags from a "type_of_work" vocabulary.
- Example and Explanation nodes each have an entity_reference targeting a client node.

I created a view listing filtered by node_type=client, no sorting, and a required relationship for **referencing entity (via field_client)**. Then I added a field for the field_client, using the relationship, and got a list that repeats the client name once for every referencing node. Turned on aggregation, and the list shortened to one entry per client. Everything works like I expected thus far.

So I add a field for the type_of_work, again requiring the relationship. Page load error. If I kill aggregation, everything looks good (except I have an entry for each referencing node because they aren't aggregated).

Am I doing something wrong here?

**EDIT:**

The goal is to get single rows that contain the client in one column, and a comma-separated list of type_of_work in the other.

Comment: If I remember correctly the issue is on the multi-value field and you have to remove the check mark from the "Display all values in the same row" in "MULTIPLE FIELD SETTINGS" to allow all values in a single row.

Comment: Still get the error. Besides that, my goal is to get the aggregated result, so that each client row has a comma-separated list of services (based on the tagged portfolio examples and explanations).